# Logging test output count in console

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, automation, nunit

every day I'm running my automated UI/API tests on Azure DevOps pipelines. Sometimes I monitor the test execution while looking at the output logs via vsTestAssembly console.

[image]

I monitor messages live whenever the test passes/fails etc. I am using Nunit

My question is: is there a possibility to log information after each test:
Lets say I have 50 tests in total that are running
I would like to log the count of the test.
Something like whenever the test passes or fails I also get a console.writeline
Test 4 out of 50

The idea is simply to be able to track how many tests ran and how many tests are still left to run

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no longer a way to get a running count (NUnit V2 had that).

However, you can get output after each test by using option `--labels:After`.

With only 50 tests, I imagine you are fairly familiar with the order in which they run, so you would know roughly how much was left at any point in time.

Adding a count to that output would require a change in the test framework, which you could, of course, request.